# I want to make a working xml file in php (encoding properly) to export data from online database to iphone

Tags: php, iphone, xml, encoding, nsxmlparser

I want to make a working xml file in php (encoding properly) to export data from online database to iphone

please tell me the coding of it...as i am new to php...don't know much :(

please help me :(

The code which I am using right now is following:

```
<?php

    // Èdition du dÈbut du fichier XML
    $xml .= '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>';
    $sml .= '<channel>'; 
    $xml .= '<title>Infonul</title>';
    $xml .= '<link>aaa</link>';
    $xml .= '<description>aaa</description>';


    // connexion a la base (mettre ‡ jour le mdp)
    $connect = mysql_connect('...-12','...','...');

    /* selection de la base de donnÈe mysql */
    mysql_select_db('...');

    // selection des 20 derniËres news
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT u.display_name as author,p.post_date as date,p.comment_count as commentCount, p.post_content as content,p.post_title as title FROM wp_posts p, wp_users u WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' and p.post_type = 'post' and p.post_author = u.id ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 0,20");


    // extraction des informations et ajout au contenu
    while($tab=mysql_fetch_array($res)){   

     $title=$tab[title];
     $author=$tab[author];
     $content=$tab[content]; //html stuff
     $commentCount=$tab[commentCount];
     $date=$tab[date];

     $xml .= '<item>';
     $xml .= '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
     $xml .= '<content><![CDATA['.$content.']]></content>';
     $xml .= '<date>'.$date.'</date>';
     $xml .= '<author>'.$author.'</author>';
     $xml .= '<commentCount>'.$commentCount.'</commentCount>';
     $xml .= '</item>'; 
    }

    // Èdition de la fin du fichier XML
    $xml .= '</channel>';
    $xml = utf8_encode($xml);

    echo $xml;

    // Ècriture dans le fichier
    if ($fp = fopen("20news.xml",'w'))
    {
     fputs($fp,$xml);
     fclose($fp);
    }

    //mysql_close();
```

?>

But this code has some errors

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to deliver XML content to the iPhone is by way of a plist.

A plist file (filename.plist) is just literally an XML format, but in a special way. It looks like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Angry Cat</string>
                <key>fileName</key>
                <string>cat_angry1.caf</string>
                <key>fileArray</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>fileName</key>
                        <string>cat_angry1.caf</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
                <key>icon</key>
                <string>icon1.png</string>
                <key>buttonIndex</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </plist>
```

So all you need to do is to output the correct headers in php:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
```

And output the database into a format similar to the format above.

From there you can use an `NSURLConnection` to download the plist and use something like the tutorial here: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/reading-and-writing-plists to read the plist format. :)

**Update after code was posted**

There are a few issues with your code. First of all on the 5th line down you have `$sml .= '<channel>';` it should be `$xml...`. Arrays should always be put in quotes. This is wrong: `$tab[commentCount]` it should be `$tab["commentCount"]` just incase there are any constants named the same.

At the top you have `$xml .= '...`. Although this might work, I've never come across it before. Just try at the very top putting `$xml = ''` before all the lines of code. Then you're initialising the variable before trying to append a string to it.

Hope some of that works. If its none of those problems then please can you post the OUTPUT of the file. Or any php errors/mysql errors you're getting, it could be something to do with that.

Comment: Sorry, but stackoverflow isn't a place to get people to MAKE scripts for you. Its to for help. I've helped you. You've now got to go and find out about database connections, getting data from mysql, parsing it, outputting it etc.

Comment: actually I already made the script..but there are errors in it

Comment: ok there are a few errors I can see in that code... I will update my answer.

Comment: $dom->createCDATASection(utf8_encode($tab['content'])) ...this code is needed to be added some where...but I don't know where

Comment: I doubt that, you don't have any objects in your code. Why doesn't the code above work?

Comment: the code above works...but not correctly...the CDATA section is missing in it